# Import bulk data to SQL Azure from Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I've got the following scenario:

1. A console application (from a third party customer) uploads a file to an Azure Blob Storage (file can be up to 2GB).
2. I've got an Azure function that's triggered when the blob has been uploaded than should do some check then upload the file to SQL Azure.

I've tried following [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/12/04/bcp-in-azure-functions/) approach, but it creates a DataSet in memory then push it on SQL Azure with SqlBulkCopy ... Is there a way I can avoid of creating a 2GB DataSet in memory in worst case?

Comment: What does the file contain? CSV? Json? XML? In order for SQLBulkCopy to have any meaning, you have to extract objects from your text file *first*.

Comment: The link you point to doesn't explain how to parse *your* file. It shows how you can use SqlBulkCopy to load data that you *already* have in a DataTable form. Sending a batch of *objects* is just as easy, eg using Fast Member's ObjectDataReader or MoreLINQ's ToDataSet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Azure Data Factory to load files from blob storage to SQL DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-data-wizard-tutorial